# Scheduled timers in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, timer, sprite-kit

I have scheduled timers that add sprite nodes to the screen as obstacles

```
func timers(){
    personTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self,     selector: #selector(spawnPerson), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    bikeTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: #selector(spawnBike), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    motorcycleTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.5, target: self, selector: #selector(spawnMotorcycle), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

I added a function to invalidate those timers. so that a bonus "level" can be ran.

```
func invalidateTimers(){
    // Obstacles
    personTimer.invalidate()
    bikeTimer.invalidate()
    motorcycleTimer.invalidate()
}
```

When the bonus is called

```
func bonus() {
    invalidateTimers()
    bonusTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self,     selector: #selector(spawnDiamonds), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

The problem that I'm having is that when the bonus is done running I invalidate the bonusTimer and recall timers(). But when I do all the timers in the function seem to be firing twice. Whats an easy workaround for that since they can't just be paused.

Comment: The SK engine is completely unaware that you have some timers running. As the answer suggests, use SKActions. They get paused when your scene pauses.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using timers, consider using SKActions, as they work well with SpriteKit. To start the timer, run:

```
let wait1 = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1)
let personTimer = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([wait1, SKAction.run {
        spawnPerson() // spawnBike() etc. for each different timer
    }]))
self.run(personTimer, withKey: "spawnPerson")
```

with modified wait values and function calls for each different timer. Then to stop the timer, run:

```
self.removeAction(forKey: "spawnPerson")
```

for each action using a different key.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using timers, you can use `update:` method of your `SKScene` subclass. It calls once per frame and has `currentTime` parameter. So you can easily calculate time intervals you need and trigger corresponding methods.

Comment: I would avoid going this route, it is unnecessary extra work added to your update cycle.  Use the built in Sprite kit functions as they are optimized to work with the Sprite kit framework

Comment: Actually you can move `person`,`bike`, `motorcycle` to GKEntities subclasses and add to it `move` GKComponent subclass... join all `move` components into GKComponent system and update it in run loop...  such updates cost not much so you can use it almost for free...

Comment: Now you are assuming they are using gameplay kit

Comment: Why not? Entity-Component good pattern and perfectly fits in this case...

Comment: Because the technology is beyond the scope of the question

Comment: Yes.... see Tob’s answer for the correct way.  If you want to make a huge elaborate answer explaining Gameplay Kit to the OP then that would be a valid answer, just don‘t expect the OP to accept it since he is clearly new to sprite kit programming.  Paradigms is the last thing he is worrying about.

Comment: You right about OP... And Tob's answer looks kinda workaround for me... I just tried to point better way from architecture point of view...

Comment: Btw, even in a GK structure, I would still not do it in the update loop.  I would use Tobs answer and have the components manage what is going on.

Comment: Ok... But reason not clear for me... You prefer workaround with `SKAction` instead of using `updateWithDeltaTime:` api of `GKComponentSystem`... with calculations that cost almost nothing...

Comment: Especially since any `SKAction` under the hood most likely uses same run loop update to calculate remaining time...

Comment: It is not a work around, it is the correct way to do it.  If you have 10000 sprites on screen, you do not want to loop through all 10000 on your update.  This means you need to constantly push and pop components or filter your list some other way.  The SKActions only run on sprites that require it.  This means less needless checking.

Comment: I bet you won't see the difference using 10000 `SKAction`'s with timers or updating  10000 `GKComponents` thought component system... Both will calculate remaining time on every run loop update ...

Comment: I bet you will,  the SKActions run no matter what, your components only add to it